# mysqli inserts data with quotes and other characters

Tags: php, mysqli

I am migrating my website from mysql_* methods to mysqli.

When I was using mysql a data like this:

```
$variable = <<<eot
    "asdasd" hello 'name name'
    // 
    \\
    "end"   
eot;
```

Was inserted in Database like follows:

```
 "asdasd" hello 'name name'
    // 
   \
    "end"
```

And it was very OK.

Now it inserts the same data like following:

```
\"asdasd\" hello \'name name\'\r\n  // \r\n \\\r\n  \"end\"
```

Can anyone please tell me how to maintain old way of inserting things into db. I do not need \ and \r and \n and such things I guess. Thanks

Comment: Aren't those the same strings? Its just the output isn't processing them the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see no difference.

Table definition:

```
create table test (s text)
```

PHP test source:

```
<?php 
$variable = <<<eot
    "asdasd" hello 'name name'
    // 
    \\
    "end"   
eot;

// mysql version
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');
mysql_select_db('test', $conn);
$sql = "insert into test values ('" . mysql_escape_string($variable) . "')";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

// mysqli version
$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'test');
$sql = "insert into test values ('" . mysql_escape_string($variable) . "')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// mysqli version (prepared statement)
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', 'test');
$sql = 'insert into test values (?)';
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
$sth->bind_param('s', $variable);
$result = $sth->execute();
```

Every version produces the same entry in the table. So, either this is just a different output you have or your code does something different.